# Database Structure for a CMS generated form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

I'm building a simple dynamic form from a database. The idea is to change the options of some fields in the form based on the ones a user sets on the CMS. So far, I've got 4 tables named: `Client`, `Orders`, `Products` and `Fields`. So, on the Form side I should get the `Field`s from the DB and then fill the options with the `Products` related to that `Field` (if they exist), then, when the user finishes typing in the data, it must create a new `Order` with all the `Field`s and the data (the chosen product). There are also, some `Field`s that their values are not related to a product(s). Finally the Order gets related to the Client by their `client_id`.

Just to clarify: The fields are static, the products displayed on them are not, and are the ones that are going to be changing.

So, 2 main questions:

- What's the ideal DB structure for this kind of problem?
- Is it a good practice to save some HTML code on the `Field` table for correctly displaying the `Field`s?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have many to many relationship among data, so you need well structured database with foreign key between the tables.

Comment: Thanks! But how should I accomplish this? Generating a new table to hold the relationship between the Field and the Order? If so, how can I set the datatype for the `value` if every field can mutate this datatype?

Comment: When you have many to many relationship you need pivot table as you have stated. Whenever data is filled and then submitted, then you have to save which client place order for which product of which field so that you can get all details later